# Вернуть заголовок 304

Tags: php, yii

Добрый вечер!

Возникла необходимость вернуть заголовок 304. НО вот что то не пойму как это делать. Почитал справку по `CHttpFilter` но что то понимания не прибавилось.

Может быть кто нибудь сталкивался и знает?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться классом CHttpException

```
throw new CHttpException(304, 'Текст сообщения');
```

Comment: Cтрого говоря, это еще вернет шаблон ошибки, что не всегда желаемо. Нативного метода правда тоже не нашел, я бы просто отнаследовался от CHttpRequest или CController и создал бы метод определения кода ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то. Данный код генерирует ошибку, а мне надо для страницы просто вернуть header. Данные хедеры нужны поисковым системам.

Comment: @BlackWidow, насколько я могу судить по просмотренному по диагонали коду, возвращаемый статус будет именно тот, который был передан первым аргументом? можете посмотреть в консоли хрома. [Пруф](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CErrorHandler#handleException-detail).

Comment: throw new CHttpException хоронит страницу. как бы die()  только поволяет вывести страницу ошибкию Я его в проектах применяю для 404 и 500 ошибок. А мне нужно чтобы сайт работал но в хедерах у него был хедер 304

Comment: @BlackWidow только руками и функцией `header()`, боюсь.

Comment: а что, в таком случае мешает в нужном месте прописать header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 304 Not Modified', true, 304) ? В данном случае, сайт будет продолжать, но при этом, возвращать код 304 вместо того же 200 на пример.